# How to embed attached fonts in my mailer?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, google-webfonts

I have try to embedding font from the google api as **font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;** in my mailer html. Anybody please help how can I add it.

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap%22%20rel=%22stylesheet

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Stint+Ultra+Condensed&display=swap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test Font mailer</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<style>
    
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Montserrat Medium'), local('Montserrat-Medium'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_ZpC3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'StintUltraCondensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Stint Ultra Condensed'), local('StintUltraCondensed-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/stintultracondensed/v9/-W_gXIrsVjjeyEnPC45qD2NoFPtBE0xCh2AOox8P6cM.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'StintUltraCondensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Stint Ultra Condensed'), local('StintUltraCondensed-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/stintultracondensed/v9/-W_gXIrsVjjeyEnPC45qD2NoFPtBE0xCh2AOrR8P.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #eeeeee;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
        
    </style>
    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="aqua">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mainWidth"
                    style="background: #fff;">
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top"><div style="font-family:'StintUltraCondensed';font-size:50px">My First test font will work.</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top"><div style="font-size:70px">My First test font will work.</div></td>
                    </tr>
                    
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```